# spring boot 2.3.1 exception in DB connection with hikari pool

Tags: spring, oracle

I'm getting exception as below, but my DB operations are successful. i want to get rid of this exception. What configuartion i'm missing in actuator or health check.

2020-07-04 01:21:24.251 ERROR 29854 [      main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool:HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.healthToCode(PrometheusConfiguration.java:72)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.lambda$null$0(PrometheusConfiguration.java:62)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:54)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$5(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:210)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:69)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.collectorNames(CollectorRegistry.java:100)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:50)
    at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:139)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$17(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.applyToCollector(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:413)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newGauge(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:207)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$gauge$1(MeterRegistry.java:295)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$registerMeterIfNecessary$5(MeterRegistry.java:559)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:612)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:566)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:559)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:295)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge$Builder.register(Gauge.java:190)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:471)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:516)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.lambda$metricsCommonTags$1(PrometheusConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.lambda$customize$0(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$null$0(LambdaSafe.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$LambdaSafeCallback.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$invoke$1(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.customize(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.configure(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.oracle.uaw.sb.RestServiceApplication.main(RestServiceApplication.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

2020-07-04 01:21:24.264  WARN 29854 [      main] o.s.b.a.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator:DataSource health check failed

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

```
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.healthToCode(PrometheusConfiguration.java:72)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.lambda$null$0(PrometheusConfiguration.java:62)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.DefaultGauge.value(DefaultGauge.java:54)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$newGauge$5(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:210)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.MicrometerCollector.collect(MicrometerCollector.java:69)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.collectorNames(CollectorRegistry.java:100)
    at io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry.register(CollectorRegistry.java:50)
    at io.prometheus.client.Collector.register(Collector.java:139)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.lambda$applyToCollector$17(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:417)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.applyToCollector(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:413)
    at io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newGauge(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:207)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$gauge$1(MeterRegistry.java:295)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.lambda$registerMeterIfNecessary$5(MeterRegistry.java:559)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.getOrCreateMeter(MeterRegistry.java:612)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:566)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.registerMeterIfNecessary(MeterRegistry.java:559)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:295)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.Gauge$Builder.register(Gauge.java:190)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:471)
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry.gauge(MeterRegistry.java:516)
    at com.oracle.uaw.configuration.PrometheusConfiguration.lambda$metricsCommonTags$1(PrometheusConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.lambda$customize$0(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$null$0(LambdaSafe.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$LambdaSafeCallback.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$invoke$1(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.customize(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryConfigurer.configure(MeterRegistryConfigurer.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MeterRegistryPostProcessor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5128)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:437)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.oracle.uaw.sb.RestServiceApplication.main(RestServiceApplication.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

Comment: it is clear that either your user or password is wrong. Oracle throws that exception in this case. You must review the pool configuration and JDBC properties

Comment: did you try to connect using sql tools to the database with the same user/password that you have in your spring boot configuration ?

Comment: in porject hibernate activites are working as expected there is no issues in it (with that i can state DB connection correct and connecting for operations). Still i can see these error regularly occuring in logs. Same configuration working with spring 2.1.4 once I update the spring 2.3.1 its start occurring the issue

Comment: Has your password any special character on it ? Which database version you have and which version of JDBC ?

Comment: Password doesn't contains any special characters, i'm using spring jpa which comes with spring boot 2.3.1. my suspect is actuator health check failing i think. not reached to conclusion yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is using SpringCloud?

If yes, try adding this to your properties:

```
spring.cloud.refresh.enabled=false
```

You also could enable logging to verify the DB connection data that HikariCP is using (the second entry is specific to HikariCP)

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```